# Can we write $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 - 2) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ as a product of fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Sometimes we can write an algebra as products of fields using Chinese Remainder Theorem. For example, $\mathbb{Z}_6 \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2 \times\mathbb{Z}_3$. Another example would be $\mathbb{F}_2 [X]/(X^2 - 1)\simeq \mathbb{F}_2 [X]/(X-1) \times \mathbb{F}_2 [X]/(X+1)$, I think. (Update: the second example is wrong)

Can we write $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 - 2) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ as a product of fields? If it's not possible, how would you show that? My thought is that the tensor product here seems to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. If I am correct then we have to that $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be written as products of fields, which I am not sure what method I should use.

Comment: It's certainly not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, since it has dimension $2\cdot 2=4$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but: your second example isn't quite right. Over $\mathbb{F}^{2}$, $X^{2}-1$ factors as $(X-1)^{2}$, since $1 \equiv -1 \pmod 2$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Oh -_- Yes, you are right since $1=-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$. I guess $\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^2-1)$ cannot be written as products then.

Comment: @EricWofsey I guess I am confused because of this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848155/difference-between-mathbbqx-x-1-otimes-mathbbq-mathbbqx-x1

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is certainly a product of fields; it's a product of one copy of itself.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That is very right, sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{2}+1) \cong \mathbb{Q}(i)$, so

$$\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{2}-2) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{2}+1) \cong \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{2}-2) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}(i) \cong \mathbb{Q}(i)[X]/(X^{2}-2)$$

Since $X^{2}-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, the last expression is a field, namely $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Ah... I didn't realize that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 + 1) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(i)$... This makes a lot of sense now